# GithubApp: is it good idea to store installation token on web client?

Tags: github-api

I'm building github app through integrations api https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/.

Authenticated user needs to be able to chose files from github repositories. Currently I'm proxying all requests (such as listing installations, repositories and git data tree) to github through my backend server.

I'm considering to give my web client a [github's installation token](https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/#create-a-new-installation-token) and save it in `sessionStorage`. This would allow to temporary perform any installation related requests to github directly from web browser. So I could list repositories/files by directly calling github api from web client without proxying through my backend api.

Would there be any security issues with this approach?

From what I can understand it should be safe to do so, because client secret and private key is kept on backend. User is only is issued a token that temporary grants API access to his own installation. I can't imagine any malicious actions user could do. Also because token is temporary, it's fairly low risk that 3rd parties could steal it from `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the GitHub Installation Access Token for several applications. As long as the pem file and application ID are at a secure location I don't see any security issue. Generating the token is a several step process(3 from what I remember) so there is some scope for error if you're not properly authorised to access your repositories.